# How to output a string with a double quotation mark?

Tags: php, quotes

I need to output a string, which is basically a java code:

I have something like this:

```
$web = "...if (url.contains('.mp4'))..."
```

I need that the single quotation mark, will be a double one, and not in html code.

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$new_str = str_replace('\'', '"', $web);
```

You could optional do it by modifying the actual string (note the use of `\` to escape the quotation marks):

```
$web = "...if (url.contains(\".mp4\"))..."
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this

```
$web = "...if (url.contains(\".mp4\"))...";
```

Answer (score 1):

Short of doing a `strtr()` replacement, just escape your double quotes:

```
$web = "...if (url.contains(\".mp4\"))..."
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double for the complete list of escaping rules.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this

```
<?php
$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new; // &lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
?>
```

see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php