# I am trying to hide and show div with js and to run other js

Tags: javascript

Hy  maybe i made some mess but i look for option witch will be show and hide results calcres div.

and basicly i stuck at this postion cus when i  add this my browser dosnt show calcres at all .

```js
 <script> <!-- Kalkulator-->
 function mycalculator() {
        var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("a").innerHTML);
        var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("odrasli").value);
        var c = parseInt(document.getElementById("c").innerHTML);
        var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("deca").value);
        var aa = a * x;
        var cc = c * y;
        var p = aa + cc;
        var d = p * 0.2;
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = p;
        document.getElementById("depozit").innerHTML = d;
  
  }
  </script>
  <script><!-- hide div-->
   function show() {
   document.getElementById('calcres').style.display = "block";
}
</script>
<script><!--js button to call both -->
function dugme() {
   mycalculator();
   show();
}
   </script>
```

```html
<div class="calculator" style="position:left;"> <!--calculator test-->
<div id =a style='display:none;'><?php echo $Data->var_price1; ?></div>
<div id =c style='display:none;'><?php echo $Data->var_price2; ?></div>
 <input id="odrasli" type="number" placeholder="Number of Adults">
 <input id="deca" type="number" placeholder="Number of Children's">
 </br>
<button value="Submit" class="submite_btn" title="Submit" type="submit" onClick="dugme()"><span class="">Get Price</span></button>
<!-- <input type="button" class= "submite_btn" value="Get Price" onClick="mycalculator()">
-->
 <div class = "calcres" style="display:none;"">
 </br>
 Grand total</br>
 <div id="price"></div> <div class="dolar">$</div></br>
 Deposite </br>
 <div id="depozit"></div> <div class="dolar">$</div></br>
</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You're using `document.getElementById('calcres')` but the `div` has the class "calcres" not the id. Change that to an id?

Comment: I try  that not working:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have `<!-- Kalkulator-->` inside `<script>` tags, Not sure if its valid. I removed those and just tried below code which worked.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

function mycalculator() {
        var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("a").innerHTML,10);
        var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("odrasli").value,10);
        var c = parseInt(document.getElementById("c").innerHTML,10);
        var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("deca").value,10);
        var aa = a * x;
        var cc = c * y;
        var p = aa + cc;
        var d = p * 0.2;
        document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = p;
        document.getElementById("depozit").innerHTML = d;

        }
function show() {
           document.getElementById('calcres').style.display = "block";
}

function dugme() {
   mycalculator();
   show();
}

</script>




<div class="calculator" style="position:left;"> <!--calculator test-->
<div id ="a" style='display:none;'>2</div>
<div id ="c" style='display:none;'>2</div>
 <input id="odrasli" type="number" placeholder="Number of Adults">
 <input id="deca" type="number" placeholder="Number of Children's">
 </br>
<button value="Submit" class="submite_btn" title="Submit" type="submit" onClick="dugme()"><span class="">Get Price</span></button>
<!-- <input type="button" class= "submite_btn" value="Get Price" onClick="mycalculator()">
-->
 <div id = "calcres" style="display:none;"">
 </br>
 Grand total</br>
    <div id="price"></div> <div class="dolar">$</div></br>
    Deposite </br>
     <div id="depozit"></div> <div class="dolar">$</div></br>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: also instead of using hidden divs , you should be using hidden input tags to hold any values

Answer (score 0):

**Your code have 3 problems that I have to tell you :**

1. You have to use `//comment` in JavaScript but not `<!-- comment -->`
   ([How to use Comment](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/website-design/website-design-basics/comment-php-javascript-html-css-code))
2. Your `<div id =a style='display:none;'>`is invalid, It should be
   `<div id ='a' style='display:none;'>`
3. A line break should be either `<br>` or `<br />` but not `</br>` ([HTML linebreak](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp))

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/v6nv4aag/2/

In addition, I think you might have some problems when outputting a double quote in PHP, [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168298/how-to-output-a-string-with-a-double-quotation-mark)